# does typescript interface property can't use "-"?

Tags: typescript

I try to use interface to case an http header, like this:

```
interface httpHeader {
    Content-Type: string;
}
export function HTTPOptionCreate(url: string, path: string, port: number, method: string, header: httpHeader) {
....
}
```

But it report:

> error| 1131[QF available]: Property or signature expected.

I guess(Because I can't find in typescript handbook) interface can't use "-", because when I delete "-" it will be all fine.

And if I am right, how can I case a JSON like variable in Typescript?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Put quotes around it?  `"Content-Type":`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
interface httpHeader {
    Content-Type: string;
}
```

To quoted string:

```
interface httpHeader {
    'Content-Type': string;
}
```